# Как получить скорость подключения к интернету в OpenBSD на C++?

Tags: c++, скорость, openbsd

Пишу программу на C++. Хочу с неё проверить скорость интернета (не speedtest, а именно, грубо говоря, интенсивность отправки/получения данных в данную секунду). В Linux есть `/sys/class/net/$(interface_name)/statistics/${rx|tx}_bytes`. Но в OpenBSD вообще нету sysfs, да и в FreeBSD подобный функционал - опциональный (`insmod /boot/kernel/sysfs.ko`). Как программно проверить скорость интернета в BSD системах?